# Concrete5 site times out on home page

Tags: php, concrete5, concrete5-8.x

I have a site built at:

http://dev5.abktech.net/WuffWalkers/

I moved the site to:

http://new.wuffwalkers.com

I changed the paths in the .htaccess, config, etc. but the home page to the site will not come up.  All of the other pages work fine, as can be seen here:

http://new.wuffwalkers.com/contact-us

Clicking through the pages all work, except the home page, which times out.

I've reloaded the database 3 times, making sure I have the foreign key constraint check disabled on my export, and anything else I can think of to make sure it's clean.  But, no luck.

I'm throwing this out in case someone has had a similar experience and can offer a suggestion of where to look next.  The new site is on GoDaddy - 1 core, 512 Mb ram.

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing anything special to the home page in .htaccess?  Have you configured canonical URL in C5 site settings?  Please post some details from these areas, maybe that will stimulate some ideas...

Comment: Is your error reporting 'on'? Please post any available errors.

Comment: UPDATE:  I was able to get the site running by removing a package and reinstalling.  The package is HonestWebsites Simple testimonials .